# Failed to load popup dialog with in views

Tags: views, 8, javascript, ajax

I am using Drupal 8.6.1 with the 8.x-1.0-alpha2 Footable module and the core dialog.

What I did so far:

- Install the Footable module.
- Download the most recent 3.x.x version of the FooTable jQuery plugin from https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/tags and move the contents of the **compiled** directory into the **libraries/footable** directory.
- I have created a simple "footable" views showing all articles with below fields:

  - Title (Title)
  - Body (Body)
  - Image (Image)
  - Tags (Tags)
- Configured the footable settings to hide the below element on any device:

  - Body (Body)
  - Image (Image)
  - Tags (Tags)
- So far, the footable view is working just as expected without no error at all.

**Here is an image:**

[image: Footable view page]

Now, I want when I click on the title field, a dialog popup will open displaying me the contents of the `/node/{{ node:nid }}` in that popup so:

- Under the advanced Section, Set the Use Ajax to: **Yes**
- Add the Content: ID to the footable view but excluded form the display.
- Edit the **title** field:

  - Uncheck the "Link to the Content" box.
  - Check the "Override the output of this field with custom text" box.
  - Add this line of code: `<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/node/{{ nid }}">{{ title }}</a>`

Now, If I visit the Footbale view page, the footable is working prefectly but when I click on any **title**, the
entire page will refresh and redirect me to `/node/{{ nid }}` path with no any dialog poping up.

Am I missing something here in my configuration ?!

**NOTE:**

If I change the view display from **Footable** to any other display like for example the built-in **Table**, the dialog will popup without any issues at all.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further Google search I found this [Webform issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3008147#comment-12823807).

**Solution:**

You have to use the Footable **dev version** and not the **alpha2** version.